# modify_if on a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm not grokking something fundamental in the `purrr::modify_if` syntax.

Say I want to do something silly--take any variable with a name 2 characters long, and cut it.

here's my attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% 
   modify_if(~. %>% 
          names %>%
          str_length %>%
          equals(2),
      function(i)
         cut_number(i, n = 2))
```

How do I pass a set of logical predictates in the first argument?

Comment: If `modify_if` is assessing each column, I don't think it is going to know about its name. In the same way that `purrr::map(mtcars, names)` or even `lapply(mtcars, names)` returns `NULL` for every result. (Happy to be proven wrong, but that's my guess).

Comment: you're exactly right--hence why this works:

   `mtcars %>% 
      modify_if(mtcars %>% 
              names %>%
              str_length %>%
              equals(2),
          function(i)
            i %>% 
            cut_interval(n = 2))`

Comment: I think you can answer your own question if you like :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @thelatemail indicates, the problem is that the first function which returns the logical predicate needs to see the name attribute. fixing this works:

```
mtcars %>% 
   modify_if(mtcars %>% 
      names %>% 
      str_length %>% 
      equals(2),
   function(i) 
      i %>% 
      cut_interval(n = 2))
```